Simple parametrization of automorphisme (Biholomorphism) over a simple annulus
Let $D   = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mbox{ with } |z|<1 \}$ be the open unit complex disk.
Let $A_r = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} \mbox{ with } 1<|z|<r \}$ be an open annulus, centered at the origin, of external radius $r$.
Question: Is there a simple parametrization of the set of all automorphisme on $A_r$ ?
(That is the biholomorphism/bijective conformal maps on $A_r \to A_r$. One can take $r=\infty$ or some fixed value, e.g. $r=2$, if it simplify the discussion.)
Related: As a special case of the Riemann mapping theorem, the set of automorphisme on $D$ can be written as
$$ \{ z \to \rho \frac{z - \alpha}{z \bar{\alpha} - 1} \mbox{ with } |\alpha|<1 \mbox{ and } |\rho|=1 \}  $$
This is essentially the unique Riemann map between two open simply connected domains, upto translation $f(\alpha)=0$ and phase of the derivative at $\alpha$. I'm looking for a similar result between two-connected domain but in the very restricted setting of the automorphismes on $A_r$.
Note: I've very little edution in complex anlysis, but Googling around I found $[1]$, so I guess there is some kind of explicit form. The setting of $[1]$ is of course much more general, I'm only interested in an application to biholomorphism $A_r \to A_r$. I've not found an answer to my question on this site, but perhaps it is buried in some comment as an obvious well known result...
$[1]$ - Bell, S.R., Deger, E. & Tegtmeyer, T. A Riemann Mapping Theorem for Two-Connected Domains in the Plane. Comput. Methods Funct. Theory 9, 323–334 (2009). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF03321730. This paper is at https://www.math.purdue.edu/~bell/papers/two.pdf.

the biholomorphisms of an annulus are just rotations and inversions $\alpha z, \alpha r/z,  |\alpha|=1$; the proof is simple since by topology the map either preserves the boundary circles or inverts them (in the sense that if $z_k \to C_1$ then $f(z_k) \to C_1$ or $f(z_k) \to C_2$ and only one or the other happens; then in the inversion case composing with $r/z$ which is obviously automorphism takes to the preserving case and then the harmonic map $\log |f|-\log |z|$ is zero on the boundary circles so is zero on the annulus hence $|f(z)|=|z|$ etc
